# Стоит ли выносить категории и подкатегории в отдельные таблицы?

Tags: база-данных

База данных для интернет-магазина. Есть таблица товаров и есть таблицы категории и подкатегории. Стоит ли две последнии таблици делать или просто записать как атрибут таблици товары?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я вижу такую схему:

```
Products:
 - Id
 - ...
 - CategoryId

Categories:
 - Id
 - ...
 - ParentCategoryId (NULL)
```

По факту категории и подкатегории - одна и та же сущность, так зачем её разделять на две таблицы? Просто сделайте `ParentCategoryId` филд и сетайте требуемый айдишник родительской категории. Если он `NULL` - значит, что это базовая категория, если есть значение - подкатегория. Тут же и решается вопрос, если вам понадобятся под-подкатегории или под-под-подкатегории и так далее.